# Is there a delay for the "INSERTED" recording binding in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I had a trigger on a SQL Server 2008 R2 table that sends me an email every time a contact form is submitted.
Like 15% of the times I get an empty email, but the records is actually inserted in the table.

Is it possible that I'm querying the `INSERTED` record before it's binding?

In any case, how do I solve this?

Here's the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER
[dbo].[SendEmail_WebContact] on [dbo].[WebContact]
AFTER INSERT AS

DECLARE @firstname      VARCHAR(50),
        @lastname       VARCHAR(50),
        @phonenumber    VARCHAR(10),
        @rdesc          VARCHAR(500),
        @body1          VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT 
    @firstname      = FirstName, 
    @lastname       = LastName,
    @phonenumber    = PhoneNumber,
    @rdesc          = RequestDescription 
FROM INSERTED;

SET @body1 = 'Name: ' + @firstname + ' ' + @lastname + CHAR(13)
                + 'Phone number:   ' + @phonenumber + CHAR(13)
                + 'Description:   ' + @rdesc + CHAR(13);

  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @recipients = 'myself@mycompany.com', 
    @subject    = 'New Web Contact Request',
    @body       = @body1;
```

**EDIT:**
Records are inserted through a form submittal on a web page. I get 2-3 per day so there will be only one record there. No bulk inserts or the like.

Comment: This code is good when there is only one insert, but it should throw an error when multiple inserts are done.

Comment: Never send email from a trigger. There's no excuse for it and it's much easier and more convenient to do it outside a trigger. Your trigger may not work as expected because it assumes only one row is updated at a time. If more than one row is updated then only one email will be sent.

Comment: @sqlvogel How do I send an email if not from the trigger when a record is inserted? BTW, records are inserted through a form submittal on a web page. I get 2-3 per day so there will be only one record there. I'll update my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem in `NULL`, use this codes

```
SET @body1 = 'Name: ' + isnull(@firstname,'') + ' ' + isnull(@lastname,'') + CHAR(13)
                + 'Phone number:   ' + isnull(@phonenumber,'') + CHAR(13)
                + 'Description:   ' + isnull(@rdesc,'') + CHAR(13);
```

In sql when you concact a string with null the result will be NULL

---

By the way your code has another problem which is not related to your question,just as a hint, when you do a bulk insert the trigger will be fired only once and all the records are in @inserted, so you need to write your trigger in a way to handle @inserted as a table consisting of multiple rows ;)

Comment: It was the NULL value!

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it, but this should work for multiple inserts.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[SendEmail_WebContact] 
ON [dbo].[WebContact]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Get results into a temp table 1st 
CREATE TABLE #Mail_Temp (
ID          INT IDENTITY(1,1),
FirstName   VARCHAR(50),
LastName    VARCHAR(50),
PhoneNumber VARCHAR(10),
rdesc       VARCHAR(500)
)

INSERT INTO #Mail_Temp (FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber,rdesc )
SELECT FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber,RequestDescription  FROM inserted


DECLARE @firstname      VARCHAR(50),
        @lastname       VARCHAR(50),
        @phonenumber    VARCHAR(10),
        @rdesc          VARCHAR(500),
        @body1          VARCHAR(MAX),
        @ID             INT;


-- Now Loop through your temp table and send emails to induviduals 

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #Mail_Temp)
     BEGIN

       -- Select only 1 record using TOP clause
        SELECT TOP 1
            @ID             = ID,
            @firstname      = FirstName, 
            @lastname       = LastName,
            @phonenumber    = PhoneNumber,
            @rdesc          = rdesc 
        FROM #Mail_Temp;


        -- Set email Body
         SET @body1 = 'Name: ' + COALESCE(@firstname,'') + ' ' + COALESCE(@lastname, '') + CHAR(13)
                    + 'Phone number:   ' + COALESCE(@phonenumber, '') + CHAR(13)
                    + 'Description:   ' + COALESCE(@rdesc, '') + CHAR(13);

         EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                                    @recipients = 'myself@mycompany.com', 
                                    @subject    = 'New Web Contact Request',
                                    @body       = @body1;

      -- Delete the record from temp table enventualy to break the loop
       DELETE FROM #Mail_Temp WHERE ID = @ID

     END
END
```